# Are there different words for an excerpt and its location in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request

In Latin, locus can be the passage of a text (e.g. Cicero says he is going to translate a passage in one of his speeches and uses locus if I remember correctly) but it can also be the location of the passage (e.g. page 10).

Does he have more precise words that distinguish these two meanings? Or at least another way to express one of the two ideas?

Comment: Could you provide an example sentence where there would a problem distinguishing between the two meanings? Such as both in one sentence or one sentence where it's unclear what *locus* means. In particular I'm wondering what use you have in mind for 'location of the passage'.

Comment: For example in a database, with one column for the text of the passage and one column for the location of the passage (page or chapter number, etc.). As far as I know the best headings would be locus for each

Comment: @Laravel That's not an example sentence. Can you edit your question to include a specific sentence (e.g. a sentence written by Cicero) with the ambiguity described by @Unbrutal_Russian?

Comment: Were pagination and books things that Cicero would have used, instead of scrolls with different line breaks in each handmade copy?  I think they numbered scrolls/books for some works and maybe verse lines, but was this done for short prose works?

Comment: @BenKovitz I actually think this is sufficient context - judging by Laravel's profile he's using Latin in a programming context, here for a UI column. The short answer is that Latin isn't hot on analytically precise terminology, maybe with the exception of scholastic Latin, a whole different beast that many would exclude from consideration. Honestly I don't even know the term English or Russian would use to indicate location without specifying type: by page, line, chapter etc. As such it's difficult to approach answering this definitely.

Comment: @Vegawatcher [I've recently researched this](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/44343/24673) and it seems that chapter references first appeared in Greek Bible scholarship around the 3th century. But prose lines or pages in codices - that would simply be inapplicable before printing where for the most part, each book was unique; although I think there did exist standardised scribal runs so to say, but rather of scrolls and not codices, and I'm not sure if they were ever as standardised so that all the lines matched up.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian The temporary solution I have found is to use verba for the passage and locus for its position in the work

Comment: This probably works, but the thing is you can just as well call the passage *locus* and the address *index* or some such. In fact it seems to correspond better to the Latin usage because I haven't seen *locus* used to express precise location, coordinates or address, it's a much more general word.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian I did not know this subtlety, your proposal seems better then, thank you. Maybe I should use verba and index and forget about locus?

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian situs might be better than index if I get the meaning correctly

Comment: No, *situs* is a very general, geographic location, situation in relation to other things - you use it in descriptions of cities and islands. It's even used of geographical or compass direction.